# How to generate a list with a specific range of numbers

Tags: arrays, vb.net, list, linq, arraylist

```
Dim myList As New List(Of Integer)(New Integer() {1001, 1006, 1011, 1016, 1021, 1026, 1031, 1036, 1041, 1046, 1051, 1056, 1061, 1066, 1071})
```

How can I reduce the code above?

Comment: _string.Join_  seems enough

Comment: It's not really clear what you're asking. Are you wanting to generate a specific sequence of numbers? What is the rule for the sequence? For example `2n + 1` would yield 3, 5, 7, 9, etc.

Comment: Not really sure what you're asking here. Are you asking how to generate these specific numbers using `Enumerable.Range`, or are you asking generally code improvements?

Comment: how about this --> Enumerable.Range(1001,71).Where(e => (e % 5) == 1).ToList()

Comment: @s.c Your C# code is also okey. Thank you. For vb.net users `Dim myList As List(Of Integer) = Enumerable.Range(start:=1001, count:=71).Where(Function(x) (x Mod 5) = 1).ToList()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The initialization of the first list could be done in this way

```
Dim init As Integer = 1001
Dim myList As IEnumerable(Of Integer) = Enumerable.Range(start:=0, count:=15).
                                        Select(Function(x) init + (x * 5))
```

The creation of the string result could be done with String.Join

```
Dim result = String.Join(Environment.NewLine, myList)
Console.WriteLine(result)
```